# On what thread does a method initiated by NSTimer run on?

Tags: multithreading, cocoa-touch, nstimer

When method `aMethod` runs as a result of an NSTimer like so:

```
NSTimer* theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 
                                                     target: self 
                                                   selector: @selector(aMethod:) 
                                                   userInfo: nil
                                                    repeats: YES];
```

Does `aMethod` run on the thread where `theTimer` was called (the main thread), or on a separate thread? Also, does the NSTimer continue repeating while `aMethod` is running, or does it wait until `aMethod` has finished?

Comment: This sounds like it might be an XY problem.

Comment: I realise it looks that way, but I'm just trying to understand the behaviour of `selector:`

Comment: Did you read the official docs? Do you have a specific question about something in the docs which is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimer` calls the selector passed in the `selector:` parameter on the thread for which the timer was scheduled.  This may or may not be the main thread.